# Where to Collect Bounty Claim?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I have a claim:

`XX,XXX CR Bounty in Federation`

Where can I collect this? I have docked in a couple space ports, checked Contacts. But nothing.

Comment: I find it amusing that this question is marked as a duplicate of a question that was asked later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you're docking at a station with the correct faction, as well as in the correct system.

If the bounty doesn't appear when you first dock, try reloading the game and check the contacts again.

Comment: how did you get it sorted? Might be useful to others.

Comment: I did just that, previously was not checking the correct faction's port.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be docked at a station that is controlled by the Federation. Note that even if a *system* is controlled by the Federation, an individual *station* may not be.